# Iterable returned by filter and assigned to variable does not seem to update

Tags: python

Question from Daily Coding Problem 11 as reproduced below:

Implement an autocomplete system. That is, given a query string s and a set of all possible query strings, return all strings in the set that have s as a prefix.

For example, given the query string de and the set of strings [dog, deer, deal], return [deer, deal].

Hint: Try preprocessing the dictionary into a more efficient data structure to speed up queries.

I have come up with a working(hopefully) solution but in the course of doing so, I came across something which I could not understand. Question below.

```
def autocomplete(word):

    words = []
    ## Set up word import wordDict
    with open('11_word_list.txt','r') as f:
        for line in f:
            words += line.split()

    ## Optional: Filter out words with same first alphabet of search word
    ## Then ensure that remaining words also are at least as long as search word
    words = filter(lambda x: x[0] == word[0], words)
    words = filter(lambda x: len(x) >= len(word), words)

    ## Strictly speaking, this is the only required line that can still
    ## make this solution work
    words = filter(lambda x: x.startswith(word), words)


####################
## Works in progress
####################

##Suppose that the content of words[] are already as long as, or longer than
##the search term, how come only Option B seems to work, but when shortened into
##Option A as a more generic form, it does not work?
##
##Put simply, it seems words[] is not updated after every run of the for loop??

## Option A

##    for i in range(1,len(word)):
##        words = filter(lambda x: x[i] == word[i], words)

## Option B

##    words = filter(lambda x: x[1] == word[1], words)
##    words = filter(lambda x: x[2] == word[2], words)
##    words = filter(lambda x: x[3] == word[3], words)

    return list(words)
```

Question as mentioned in commented block.
Option B was first written to test the concept and it worked, although it is hardcoded. Option A was an attempt to generalise Option B but it seems that words variable is not being updated despite the assignment at the front and it keeps reading from the original words array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues that combine to cause the problem. Fixing either one would prevent the larger problem.

The first issue is that `filter` is a lazy iterator. It doesn't actually process its input immediately. It only skips over bad values as you iterate on its output iterator. That's a good thing if you might quit iterating early, but it's problematic here. You could avoid your problem by using a non-lazy approach to filtering, like a list comprehension (or you could do `list(filter(...))`):

```
for i in range(1,len(word)):
    words = [x for x in words if x[i] == word[i]]
```

The reason the lazy `filter` is problematic is our second issue. This is that your `lambda` functions are closures. They're reading the `i` variable from the enclosing namespace, not from their own namespace. Unfortunately, since `i` keeps changing in the outer namespace as the loop goes on, they all end up seeing the last `i` value, rather than the value `i` had when they were defined. There's a fix for this, which is to use `i` as an argument in the `lambda`, with its current value (in the outer namespace) as the default value:

```
for i in range(1,len(word)):
    words = filter(lambda x, i=i: x[i] == word[i], words)
```

Note that neither of these fixes is going to result in very efficient prefix matching. For a really efficient search, you probably want to load the data file just once, and build a data structure that can be efficiently searched for prefixes. A trie does that by default, but if you don't want to build one yourself (or use a library), a basic dictionary mapping from prefixes to full strings might be reasonable if you don't have too many words.